Docker: error while creating mount source path
I am new to Docker. I am trying to run a container on MacOS. However, when I run:
docker compose up -d --build

I get the following error:
Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/host_mnt/Users/admin/Desktop/ModelFly/atryon': mkdir /host_mnt/Users/admin/Desktop: operation not permitted

I don't know if this has something to do with the permissions of the source directory. Here is my docker-compose.yml file:
version: '3'

services:
  extension:
    container_name: extension
    hostname: extension
    restart: always
    tty: true
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5173:5173
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    command: yarn dev --host
    networks:
      - default
    platform: linux/amd64

networks:
  default:

Dockerfile:
FROM node:20-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN yarn install

COPY . .


Welcome to DevOps! Can you also include your Dockerfile along with your question?

Added just now!

Looks like the docker or docker group does not have permission to make a folder in the path. Update your permissions and try again.

This worked, thanks!

In my case, switching from VirtioFS to gRPC FUSE in Docker desktop > Settings > General > Virtual Machine Options fixed it.
